# Absolute Newbie and cant comprehend C++

Tags: c++

im a newbie in c++. I have a lab that has been assigned to me which has 7 question in it. im already finished 5 question which leave me 2 question left.

Here's the question

6 .Modify any of the program written in (4) or (5) so that the user will be able to modify
the nickname of the selected author.

7 . Modify the above program so that the user will be able to assign an author to a book in the list . You may require adding a new member of the Author structure to represent book authored . The program should display the author details with the book written. Assume that one author can only write one book

Here is the working code that i choose which is from question no.4 which require me to modify the code by implementing array and call by value.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Author {

int id ;
string fullname;
string nickname;
int age ;

};


struct Book {

int id ;
string title;
int year;
float price ;

};


void menu (){

cout << "Add New Author (1) \n" ;
cout << "Display Author List (2)\n " ;
cout << "Add New Book (3) \n" ;
cout << "Display Book List (4) \n" ;
cout << "Quit The Program (0) \n\n" ;

cout << "Please Enter The Number : " ;

}


Author addauthor(Author v , int x){

cout << "Enter ID: ";
cin  >> v.id;
cout << "Enter Full Name: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin ,v.fullname) ;
cout << "Enter nickname: ";
cin  >> v.nickname;
cout << "Enter Age: ";
cin  >> v.age;

cout << endl ;

return v ;

}

void displayauthor(Author v ){

cout << "ID: " << v.id << endl;
cout << "Full Name: " << v.fullname << endl;
cout << "Nickname: " << v.nickname << endl ;
cout << "Age: " << v.age << endl << endl;


}


Book addbook(Book v , int x){

cout << "Enter ID: ";
cin  >>  v.id;
cout << "Enter Title: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin ,v.title);
cout << "Enter Year: ";
cin  >>  v.year;
cout << "Enter Price : RM";
cin  >>  v.price;

cout << endl ;

return v ;

}

void displaybook(Book v ){

cout << "ID: " << v.id << endl;
cout << "Title: " << v.title << endl;
cout << "Year: " << v.year << endl ;
cout << "Price: RM" << v.price << endl << endl;

}


int main()

{

int n ;
Author a[5];
Book b[5];

int i ;



while (n !=0){

menu();
cin >> n ;

{

if (n==1) {


 for(i = 0 ;i < 5 ; i++ )

{
    
 a[i]= addauthor(a[i] , i);

    }
}

 else if (n==2) {


 cout << "\nAuthor Information." << endl << endl;
 
 for(i = 0 ;i < 5 ; i++ )

{
    
 displayauthor(a[i]);

    }
}

else if (n==3) {

for( i = 0 ;i < 5 ; i++ )

{
    
 b[i]= addbook(b[i] , i);

    }
}

else if (n==4) {

 cout << "\nBook Information." << endl << endl;

 for(i = 0 ;i < 5 ; i++ )

{
    
 displaybook(b[i]);
 
    }

}

else {

cout << "The number you've enter is not available"<< endl << endl ;

    }

  }

}


cout << "Program end" ;

return 0;
}
```

To summarize my question is :

1. How do I code it so that it can modify the nickname for the selected author? Meaning that how do I overwrite the old nickname that has been assign to the author (Question 6)
2. How do I write a code so that the user can assign an author to a book in the list? What member Author that needs to be added and how do I display it. (Question 7)

I hope you guys can help me, ive been trying to figure it out for a past couple days
Thank you .

Comment: Please focus on what you are stuck at. Adding a menue option for nickname changing? Reading in the new nickname? Overwriting the old nickname? Show a [mre] from all the steps before the one you are stuck with.

Comment: Unrelated: `int i;` and `addauthor(a[i], i);` makes your program have undefined behavior since you reed `i` which is uninitialized. The argument isn't even used in the function so just remove it.

Comment: Analysising code (and helping you) becomes easier with consistent indentation and without exaggerated whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

1. Looking at your code and your style it seems that the most easy to understand for you will be to have a function that gets `Author` as parameter and returns modified `Author` struct. Something like this:

```cpp
Author changeNickname(Author author) {
    getline(cin, author.nickname);
    return author;
}

// Example how to call
int main() {
    Author a;
    a = changeNickname(a);
}
```

Here you should also note that `author` would be actually a copy of parameter you are passing to it due to how C++ works. If you want to modify existent `Author` object then you can use pointers:

```cpp
void changeNickname(Author *author) {
    getline(cin, author->nickname);
}

// Example how to call
int main() {
   Author a;
   changeNickname(&a);
}
```

2. Using pointers you can set a pointer to an author in `Book` struct:

```cpp
struct Book {

int id ;
string title;
int year;
float price ;
Author *author;
};
```

Now you can have an author linked to a book like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    Author a;
    Book b;
    b.author = &a;
}
```

If you want to print some information about an Author and you have a pointer then you need to change all `.` calls to `->`:

```cpp
int main() {
    Book b;
    cout << b.author->nickname << endl;
    // Same as above line
    cout << (*(b.author)).nickname << endl;
}
```

Comment: For the nickname part, how do i make it so that it can only choose the SELECTED author and not make it change other author's name